Proper time of two particles being the same when they are under a tree-level interaction
I have a question: I have a figure like this:

The interpretation of the diagram is this: a particle is emitted at $x_2$, interacts with the field at $x_1$ and from $x_1$ another particle is emitted with same momentum as the original particle. My question is, is the proper time of both the particles same?

Comments to the post (v3): 1. What is the significance of the rest of the diagram, which doesn't look like tree-level? 2. How does knowing both position $x_1$ and momentum $k$ not conflict with the HUP? 3. Is this from a reference? Which pages?

The answer to question 2 is that ultimately we will be integrating $x_1$ all over. For the first question, I actually meant a kind of a Feynman blob representing the remaining portion of the process. My doubt is in an answer to this question which said that we can make the proper time of both the particles the same. My doubt is why we can do this. And, can we say the same for any two particles which are separated by say a one-loop in the diagram? Actually I want to get a complete answer from the starting because I have no idea about how to associate proper times to particles.The answer given

has confused me...

No actually this has no reference... I want to solve a problem which requires knowing the relation between the proper times of two particles that are part of a diagram just like this.

If you want it to be the same then you can set it to be the same. The proper time $\tau$ does not have any particular physical significance. What is important is $d\tau$. So you can set $\tau$ how you like at $x_1$.

Thank you... but I didn't fully understand:  Could you please explain it... I didn't understand how we can set the proper time to be the same: the time coordinates of the two particles are $t_1, t_2$ . Does being able to set the same proper time to both require the process (of the interaction between the two), to be at tree level?

You can arbitrarily choose to set them the same if you wish. You can arbitrarily choose to set them different if you wish. It makes no physical difference.

Okay... I get it, thanks. My confusion is that can we do this only if the two particles are under a tree level interaction or can we set the proper time as same of two particles which are anywhere in the Feynman graph as long as the whole graph is connected ?
